# How to show $A \setminus (V \cap A) = A\cap(X \setminus V)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question:

Suppose that $A, V$ are subsets of $X$. Prove that

$A \setminus (V \cap A) = A\cap(X \setminus V)$

Try:
$A \setminus (V \cap A)= (A \setminus V) \cup (A \setminus A)  = A \setminus V = A\cap X \setminus V$

whats next?

Comment: Didn't you prove this already? What's the question?

Comment: Next is: add "qed."

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Hmm i did not notice that I had already proved it :)

Comment: As already said in a (now deleted) comment, the identities you used to prove it seem to me as (un-)obvious as the assertion itself. I don’t know how convinced you are of them, but maybe you could try to prove them next.

Also, maybe you’re thinking $A \cap X \setminus V = (A \cap X) \setminus V$ which would explain the missing parentheses.
Then you’d have to show $(A \cap X) \setminus V = A \cap ( X \setminus V)$.
You can surely just use other identities to arrive there as you did before or just accept that as obvious as well.
It really depends on what you want to understand.

Comment: Generally, a way to convince yourself of set equalities is by splitting them up into proving “$\subseteq$” and “$\supseteq$” by following an arbitrary element of one set to the other and vice versa.

Comment: By the way, you can get a "$\setminus$" in $\LaTeX$ with "\setminus".

Comment: @K.Stm., suree, it's the axiom of extensionality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#1._Axiom_of_extensionality

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Related question (almost a duplicate): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/43771/11994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in A-(V\cap A).\;$ Then $$x\in A,~\wedge~ x\in (V\cap A)'$$  or $$x\in A,~\wedge~ x\in (V'\cup A')$$ or $$x\in A,~\wedge~ (x\in V'\vee x\in A')$$ or $$(x\in A,~\wedge~ x\in V')\vee (x\in A, ~\wedge~ x\in A')$$ or $$x\in(A\cap V')~\vee~x\in\emptyset$$ or equivalently $$x\in A\cap(X-V)$$

Comment: Nice a staightforward. I like +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for it.

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice solution to you and amWhy both - both so clean! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks, but she runs fast ahead than me. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: you're done! ;-)

---

If you'd like to be more *transparent,* you can show this by "*chasing elements*":

> $$x\in A\setminus(V\cap A)\tag{1}$$

$$\implies \; x\in A\;\land\;  x\notin (V\cap A)\tag{Definition: Set Minus}$$

$$\iff \; x\in A\;\land\; (x\notin V \,\lor\, x \notin A)\tag{De Morgan's}$$

$$\iff (x\in A\,\land\, x\notin V)\;\lor \;(x\in A \,\land\, x\notin A)\tag{Distributivity}$$

$$\iff (x\in A\,\land\, x\notin V)\,\lor \,x \in \varnothing\;\tag{why?}$$ 
$$\iff \; (x\in A\,\land\, x\notin V)\tag{why?}$$

$$\iff \;x \in A\, \land \,(x \in X \,\land\, x \notin V)\;\tag{why?}$$ 
$$\iff \; x\in A \,\land\, x\in X\setminus V\tag{Definition, set minus}$$

> $$\iff\; x\in A\cap(X\setminus V) \tag{Definition, intersection $(2)$}$$

$$\therefore\quad A \setminus (V \cap A) = A\cap(X \setminus V)$$

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Nice solution to you and Babak both - both so clean! +1